# 'BaseSettings' has been moved to the 'pydantic-settings' how to correct this in VS code when preparing data analysis report

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

df = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')
print(df)

profile = ProfileReport(df)
profile.to_file(output_file="housing.html")
```

'BaseSettings' has been moved to the 'pydantic-settings'    how to correct this in VS code when preparing data analysis report

'BaseSettings' has been moved to the 'pydantic-settings'    how to correct this in VS code when preparing data analysis report